# Using a value from a file and updating it using a Linux script:

Tags: linux, bash, git, text-editing, commit

I have an automatic build script for my build server that builds Android applications.
As part of this building process, I need to increment two parameters in one of the Android application files after the build and commit this file into the Git repository.

So I have to build the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "Start of Pull command"
git pull
echo "End of Pull command"
echo "Start of incrementedRelease build"
gradle incrementedRelease
echo "End of incrementedRelease build"
echo "Start of Commit command"
git commit -a -m "======================== Commit to change Manifest Version ======================"
echo "End of Commit command"
echo "Start of Push command"
git push
echo "End of Push command"
```

Now, the issue is that instead of creating a commit with the name:

> Commit to change Manifest Version

I want to pass the current application version.

For I have created a `version.txt` file that contains the current version that will be released,
I want in the process of the build for it to get the value from this file and put it as part of the commit name, as well as update this file automatically with the next version for the next commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your version.txt put it as a shell variable such as `APPVER="version"`

Then in your bash script use `. /path/to/version.txt`
then export the variable with the line `export APPVER`

this will then import that variable into your build script and use it where you want the name by using the variable $APPVER

`Commit to change Manifest $APPVER`

in answer to comment

```
MAJOR=`echo $APPVER| cut -c1-1`
export MAJOR

MINOR=`echo $APPVER | cut -c3-5`
export MINOR


NEWVER=$((MINOR + 1))
export NEWVER


echo APPVER=$MAJOR.$NEWVER > /path/to/version.txt
```

EDIT: forgot to add the export command
EDIT: added way to increment... and fixed some mistakes and formating

Comment: So, few questions: as I understand in order for the file to be available I need to to add it with a (dot)(.) to the begging of the script, and right after it add export APPVER in the scrpit. this will allow me to use $APPVER in the commit name?

Comment: Lets say that the text in the file is APPVER="1.110" how can I increment the version by 1 to "1.111"?

Comment: Well this works great, I just left with upgrading the file to the new version. Could you tell me how can I update the APPVER parameter in the version.txt file?

Comment: The problem is bash doesn't deal with floating point numbers such as 1.110 it can only handle integers, i have thought of an idea that may do the job but would involve rules around how your version is done - i will add it to my answer

Comment: So what if I make two parameters in my version file: MAJOR and MINOT and I connect them on output like $MAJOR+"."+$MINOR (If it's even written this way in Linux) and update only the minor version. This would be sufficient for me, can this be done?

Comment: Yes, see my edit to the answer

Comment: Thanks for you help, there is only one problem. When the file is rewritten the new version is assigned only the file is changed to version only without the APPVER

Comment: yes, i saw my mistake and have edited to reflect the correct echo into the file, sorry

Comment: Yes, seen this now. Let me check this for a sec.